# Find the sum of infinite series $\cos{\frac{\pi}{3}}+\frac{\cos{\frac{2\pi}{3}}}{2}+..$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, summation

Find the sum of infinite series $$\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{3}}+\dfrac{\cos{\dfrac{2\pi}{3}}}{2}+\dfrac{\cos{\dfrac{3\pi}{3}}}{3}+\dfrac{\cos{\dfrac{4\pi}{3}}}{4}+\dots$$

I tried to convert it to $\mathrm{cis}$ form, and tried to convert to to integration of something, but nothing proved to be helpful, any hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your idea works!

Let $A=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k}\cos\frac{\pi k}{3}$, $B=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{\pi k}{3}$ and $z=\operatorname{cis}\frac{\pi}{3}.$

Thus, $$A+Bi=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{z^k}{k}=...$$
and take a real part.

Comment: Thank you! Have pity on me :(

Comment: @Zenix You are welcome!

Comment: I got it, but how to proceed further. I know it's something really easy, but I still can't proceed... A small hint..

Comment: For example, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2039146